# Doubly Linked List - RemoveFirst Method

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I need help with following Code:

```
public boolean remove(Integer value) {

    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        if (head == tail) {
            head = tail = null;
        }
    } else {


    }

    size--;

    return false;
}
```

And this is my task:

"removes the    first   occurrence  of  the specified   value   from    this    list"

It s a method of a Doubly Linked List.

So far I think I did correct but I am still missing the "else" part and I have no clue what to put inside...

I also have a class with a constructor and getter- and setter- methods.

Here is my node class:

```
public class ListElement {

    private Integer value;
    private ListElement next;
    private ListElement prev;

    public ListElement(ListElement prev, Integer value, ListElement next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public ListElement getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public ListElement getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setNext(ListElement next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setPrev(ListElement prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to find the node that contains `value` and then unlink it. Your `if/else` needs to be removed as the first `if (isEmpty())` handles that case.

Comment: I think you want the else inside of the second if statement.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, sir! Fixed that part.

Comment: Please post your Node class

Comment: `[teach-me]` Please ask your teacher about this. SO will provide some code for you, but a real teacher will do a much better job.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this `if` should be removed as you already test for empty

```
if (!isEmpty()) {
    if (head == tail) {
        head = tail = null;
    }
} else {


}
```

Then you can process like:

```
public boolean remove(Integer value) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    if (head == tail) {
        if (head.getValue() == value) {
            head = tail = null;
        } else  {
            // Not found, return false
            size--;
            return false;
        }
    }

    ListElement current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getValue() == value) {
            // Found
            if (current.getPrev() == null) {
                // current node is head node
                head = current.getNext();
                current.setPrev(null);
            } else if (current.next() == null) {
                // current node is tail node
                tail = current;
                current.setNext(null);
            } else {
                // Current node is in the middle
                ListElement prev = current.getPrev();
                ListElement next = current.getNext();
                prev.setNext(next);
                next.setPrev(prev);
            }
            size--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Not found
    size--;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the Code is not working!? And I find it really confusing. Hard to understand for me to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by the function signature that you want to delete the element with the specific value. You need to find that node and remove it:

```
public boolean remove(Integer value) {

    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    ListElement found = head;
    // Try to find it
    while (null != found && !found.value.equals(value)) {
         found = found.next;
    }
    // Not found?
    if (null == found) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    // Found. Unlink
    if (found.prev != null) found.prev.next = found.next;
    else head = found.next;
    if (found.next != null) found.next.prev = found.prev;
    else tail = found.prev;

    size--;

    return true;
}
```